# DocumentBuilder parse response from DefaultHttpClient but not from the faster HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, xml, httpclient

I have the following class 'MainActivity' it has 2 methods downloadPageA and downloadPageB both of them retrieve content over a http connection once the content is downloaded the XMLfromString method tries to parse it to a Document-Object.

**Problem:** downloadPageA works as expected but downloadPageB crashes at parsing.

**Class:**

```
package com.example.testhttp;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;  

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException; 

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new Worker().execute("");
    }
    public static Document XMLfromString(String v) {
            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource is = new InputSource();
                    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(v));
                    doc = db.parse(is);
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return doc;
    }

    public static String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String s = "";
            String line = "";
            BufferedReader rd = null;
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                            s += line;
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return s;
    }
    public static String downloadPageA(String url) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                    return inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e1) {
            }
            return null;
    }
    public static String downloadPageB(String url) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            URL serverAddress = null;
            try {
                    serverAddress = new URL(url);
                    connection = null;
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    connection.connect();
                    return inputStreamToString(connection.getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    connection.disconnect();
                    connection = null;
            }
            return "";
    }
    private class Worker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Document domA = XMLfromString(downloadPageA("http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Mario"));
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Document domB = XMLfromString(downloadPageB("http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Mario"));

                    return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            }
    }
    }
```

**stacktrace:**

```
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected <! (position:START_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.StringReader@4166bfd0) 
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at com.example.testhttp.MainActivity.XMLfromString(MainActivity.java:64)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at com.example.testhttp.MainActivity$Worker.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:119)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at com.example.testhttp.MainActivity$Worker.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-13 19:39:06.352: W/System.err(28733):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-13 19:39:06.362: W/System.err(28733):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I would like to use HttpUrlConnection, it is faster and the android team advise to use it instead of HttpClient. An explanation of this error would be very nice!

Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! *downloadPageA* and *downloadPageB* don't get the same result because they use diffrent user-agents strings!

In *downloadPageB* I used:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)");
```

to set the user-agent equal to the user-agent of the HttpClient in the method *downloadPageA*.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using an Android Service for your REST requests. [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) offers :

- Android Service to execute requests, much better than an async task (did you ever try to rotate your device during your request ??)
- caching
- much easier parsing if you use SpringAndroid module...

Comment: I'm using asynctask because I only download data in case of an userinput and display it right after it got downloded.

yes i did try to rotate the device during the request it works es expected

Comment: sure, but try rotating the device while downloading, just for fun.

Comment: it works `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` ;)

Comment: but anyway RoboSpice seams to be an interesting project!